How can i do this Feynman diagram?
I just started using the feynmp package and i'm trying to draw a feynman diagram like this (sorry for the bad drawing). Basically its supposed to be a photon being emmited and absorved again.

However, all i could do was

This is the code:
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\begin{document}
\unitlength = 1mm
\begin{fmffile}{simple_labels}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(60,30)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1}
\fmflabel{$e^+$}{i2}
\fmflabel{$\mu^+$}{o2}
\fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2,o1}
\fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}

I´ve tried to find simillar examples but couldn't find any.

I'm a bit rusty with feynmf so there might be more efficient ways than this. The idea is to freeze the diagram without the loop, introduce invisible lines to define the two vertices along the fermion line, and draw the photon line last.
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\unitlength=1mm
\begin{fmffile}{simple_labels}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(60,30)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1}
\fmflabel{$e^+$}{i2}
\fmflabel{$\mu^+$}{o2}
\fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2,o1}
\fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v1,v2}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{phantom}{v1,m1}\fmf{phantom,tension=.5}{m1,m2}\fmf{phantom}{m2,i2}
\fmf{photon,tension=0,right}{m1,m2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}



Thank you! That's exactly what i wanted it to look like.
